# Does Z3 give the minimal unsatisfiable core up to now?

Tags: z3

I want to know if Z3 now can give the minimal unsatisfiable core now.
Or is there someone has developed a good support for this? Does anybody know this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Z3 produces unsatisfiable cores, but they are *not* necessarily minimal.

Here is an example on how to extract unsat cores:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/smtc_core

You may also want to check the following questions:

[Soft/Hard constraints in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439556/soft-hard-constraints-in-z3)

[Label on SMT-LIB 2.0 assertions in z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804163/label-on-smt-lib-2-0-assertions-in-z3)